# Only show repos in gitweb that user has access to via Gitolite

Tags: apache, ubuntu, gitolite, gitweb

I have gitolite setup and working with SSH key based auth. I can control access to repos via the gitolite-admin.git repo and the conf file. All of this works great over SSH but I would like to use GitWeb as a quick way to view the repos.

GitWeb is working great now but shows all repositories via the web interface. So my goal here is to:

- Authenticate users in apache2 via PAM, I already have the Ubuntu server authenticating aginst AD and all the users are available. This should not be an issue.
- Use the user name logged in with the check gitolite permissions
- Display apropriate REPOS in the web interface.

Does anyone have a starting point for this?  The Apache part shouldn't be difficult, and I'll set it to auth all fo the /gitweb/ url. I dont know how to pass that username around and authorize it against gitolite. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to complete the gitweb config scripts in order to call gitolite.

The key is in the `gitweb_config.perl`: if that file exists, gitweb will include and call it.
See my [`gitweb/gitweb_config.perl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl) file:

```perl
our $home_link_str = "ITSVC projects";
our $site_name = "ITSVC Gitweb";
use lib (".");
require "gitweb.conf.pl";
```

In [`gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/c1ec1e4bb4dedea93bc251d8395c9c7627c08440/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl) (custom script), I define the official callback function called by gitweb: **[`export_auth_hook`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67de23ddb1ed5471e302f6a84fae7a9037a0d980/Documentation/gitweb.conf.txt#L183-L189)**: that function will call gitolite.

```perl
use Gitolite::Common;
use Gitolite::Conf::Load;
#$ENV{GL_USER} = $cgi->remote_user || "gitweb";

$export_auth_hook = sub {
  my $repo = shift;
  my $user = $ENV{GL_USER};
  # gitweb passes us the full repo path; so we strip the beginning
  # and the end, to get the repo name as it is specified in gitolite conf
  return unless $repo =~ s/^\Q$projectroot\E\/?(.+)\.git$/$1/;

  # check for (at least) "R" permission
  my $ret = &access( $repo, $user, 'R', 'any' );
  my $res = $ret !~ /DENIED/;

  return ($ret !~ /DENIED/);
};
```

---

From the comments:

`GL_USER` is set because of the line:

```perl
$ENV{GL_USER} = $cgi->remote_user || "gitweb";
```

`$cgi->remote_user` will pick the environment `REMOTE_USER` set by any Apache Auth module which has completed the authentication (like in this [Apache configuration file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/c1ec1e4bb4dedea93bc251d8395c9c7627c08440/apache/env.conf.tpl#L99-L134)).
You can print it [with a 'die' line](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/c1ec1e4bb4dedea93bc251d8395c9c7627c08440/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl#L17).

"Could not find Gitolite/Rc.pm" means the INC variable used by perl doesn't contain $ENV{GL_LIBDIR}; (set to `~/gitolite/lib` or `<any_place_where_gitolite_was_installed>/lib`).
That is why there is a line [in the same `gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/c1ec1e4bb4dedea93bc251d8395c9c7627c08440/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl#L22-L24) file which adds that to `INC`:

```perl
unshift @INC, $ENV{GL_LIBDIR};
use lib $ENV{GL_LIBDIR};
use Gitolite::Rc;
```

Edit from Nat45928: in my case I needed to insert my home path into all the '@H@' entries. That solved all of my issues right away.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow all of this. How does GitWeb Know the inital username to start all of this with?

Comment: @nat45928 because of the line `$ENV{GL_USER} = $cgi->remote_user || "gitweb";`: the authentication is supposed to be done by Apache before calling gitweb: see https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/c1ec1e4bb4dedea93bc251d8395c9c7627c08440/apache/env.conf.tpl#L99-L134: the last line is calling gitweb `DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi`.

Comment: Ah, ok. And the $cgi->remote_user is pulling the info from the Apache2 session setup with the "AuthType form" entry? So any type of Apache Auth mod can be used? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nat45928 yes, as long as that Auth mod (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) has set the `$REMOTE_USER` variable.

Comment: the $REMOTE_USER variable being that $cgi->remote_user? Is there a way I can tell if that has been set?

Comment: @nat45928 yes,  `$cgi->remote_user` will have the content of `$REMOTE_USER`. I generally set some die debug lines to check its content, as in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/c1ec1e4bb4dedea93bc251d8395c9c7627c08440/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl#L17

Comment: Awesome. I am going to give this a whirl starting with Basic auth in apache2. I'll mark it as the answer if everything works.

Comment: Threw a "Could not find Gitolite/Rc.pm" seems like the gitolite RC file. Looks like `use Gitolite::RC;` is the line that screwed it up. any ideas on how to link those?

Comment: @nat45928 what gitolite version are you using?

Comment: @nat45928 note that the sources like `Gitolite/Rc.pm` is known because of the line `unshift @INC, $ENV{GL_LIBDIR};`, which adds to the PERL `@INC` variable the path to the Gitolite library perl scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59126/discussion-between-nat45928-and-vonc).

Comment: @nat45928 sorry, I went to bed a bit before your chat invitation.

Comment: @nat45928 yes, the scripts I link are not meant to be used as is. Any @H@ are templates to be replace by actual values.

Comment: Yep, that's what tripped me up. I thought it was odd but I had never seen that notation. But otherwise your scripts worked flawlessly. A lot easier than I imaged this would be. Thanks again!